# detect client location using client ip

Tags: php

I'm not familiar with server and all. But in my recent project I have to fetch client ip address and their country. Here is my code:

```
$ipaddress = '';
//   get user ip address
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
      $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
  else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
      $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
  else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
      $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
  else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
      $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
  else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
      $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
  else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
      $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  else
      $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
  echo $ipaddress."<br>"; 
  
  //get user country code
  $client_country = file_get_contents('https://ipapi.co/'.$ipaddress.'/country_code/');
  echo $client_country."<br>";
```

To test this i'm using some vpn extensions. But ip address is always 192.168.0.1 and client_country is undefined. Why ip address is always same?

Comment: Isn't it always going to be the case that if your client is connecting via a VPN, they're going to present a client address on your local network, rather than their actual client address? What is in those `$_SERVER[]` variables when you `var_dump()` them? If you present a non-routable address to your country-checking service, then I'd expect you're always going to get "unknown" back as it cannot possibly know - these addresses are used on LANs all around the world.

Comment: thanks to that error you can detect vpn and take advantage if you want to deny specific user eg in a game platform (anti cheating)   and you can solve this too  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797424/php-include-check-php-to-check-if-the-user-has-a-vpn

Comment: also you can study a tracing method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463819/php-script-to-traceroute over that vpn if you have access to that platform game local witch uses that vpn